# How to use Ontonotes LDC corpus with Stanford Parser

Tags: nlp, tagging, stanford-nlp

How different is the format for ontonotes from penn treebank? Could I train a model of ontonotes on the Stanford Parser? If not, how could develop a ontonotes tree parser for the Stanford Parser.